# RestSharp StatusCode vs IsSuccessful

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I have the following class

```cs
public class Customer 
{
    public Customer() 
    {
        Project = new HashSet<Project>();
    }

    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    
    public HashSet<Project> Project { get; set; }
}
```

And the following method

```cs
protected async Task<IRestResponse> ApplyRequest<T>(string resource, 
    Method method, T data) where T: class, new() 
{
    var client = new RestClient(_connectionConfig.BaseUrl);
    
    client.FollowRedirects = false;
    
    var request = new RestRequest(resource, method);
    request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddParameter("application/json",
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), ParameterType.RequestBody);
        
    //request.AddJsonBody(data); 
    //This also doesn't work
    
    var response2 = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<T>(request);
    
    return response2;
}
```

---

Now if I call this method with Post method, the return statuscode is "created" (and it is actually created). However, the property IsSuccessful gives "false" and the error message is

> "Unable to cast object of type 'SimpleJson.JsonArray' to type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'."

Is this usual, or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not successful because you had a serialisation error.  I also see you logged it on GiTHub and got the same response. https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1064